# How to position image buttons on top of page

Tags: css, wordpress, html, positioning

I am trying to add two buttons on the top of this page:

```
http://213.229.81.180/~demo/
```

I have managed to add them via putting this code:

```
<div class="hochzeit-button-header"><a href="http://213.229.81.180/~demo/portfolio-hochzeit/"><img id="hochzeit-button" src="http://213.229.81.180/~demo/wp-content/themes/creativepearl_child/btn_hochzeit.png" alt="hochzeit button" title="hochzeit button"></a></div>

<div class="portrait-button-header"><a href="http://213.229.81.180/~demo/portfolio-portrait/"><img id="portrait-button" src="http://213.229.81.180/~demo/wp-content/themes/creativepearl_child/btn_portrait.png" alt="portrait button" title="portrait button"></a></div>
```

The problem remains that now all the other content in the menu has moved down, so the Header is getting too big.

I would like to have the images just float on top of the other stuff in the menu like the facebook, google plus buttons.

Comment: You need to provide some css codes for the buttons. First try positioning them and than ask in here. By the way, your header is too big with or without the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to absolutely position the buttons inside the header.  To do so, add `position:relative` to the button's parent element and add `position: absolute` and something like `top: 10px; right: 30px;` to the buttons.